# how to trigger resize function according to window width

Tags: jquery, window-resize

In the following code, I detach my navigation bar and place it somewhere else if the width of the screen is bigger than `1000px`. The only thing is that such behavior only happens if I refresh the page.

How can I trigger the resize function so that the navbar can be detached both when I trigger or refresh the page?

```
var maximum = 1000; 
var element = $('nav#site-navigation').detach();    
if($(window).width() <= maximum ) {
  element;
  $('header').after(element);
}
```

Comment: Put this code in a `resize()` event handler. Also, it would be much better if you did this with responsive CSS, instead of JS, if possible.

Comment: But if I put everything in a resize function, the code will not work if I open the site on a cellphone. Cause the code will only happen when the page is being resized.

Comment: Have you try with css media query..

Comment: I cannot use css media query to detach an element

Comment: @Ragmah then raise a `resize()` event manually, so that the logic is executed on load too.

Comment: also keep in mind that `resize` handler might fire frequently causing too much load to the browser - it is a good practice to use some kind of `debouncing`

Answer (score 0):

```
function placeHeader(){
   var maximum = 1000; 
   if($(window).width() <= maximum ) {

      var element = $('nav#site-navigation').detach(); 
      $('header').after(element);
   }
}
$(window).load(function(){
   placeHeader();
});
$(window).resize(function(){
   placeHeader();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Readjusting Mateusz Kudej code, there you have

```
function placeHeader(){
    var maximum = 1000; 
    if($(window).width() <= maximum ) {
       var element = $('nav#site-navigation').detach(); 
       $('header').after(element);
    }
    if($(window).width() > maximum ) {
       var element = $('nav#site-navigation').detach(); 
       $('div.site-branding').after(element);
    }
 }  
 $(window).load(function(){
    placeHeader();
 });
 $(window).resize(function(){
    placeHeader();
 });
```